# How to define elements of a Struct in the Header File?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I´am new at C++, so heads up.
I want to make a Blackjack Game and have a Struct with two Elements, name and points for the Cards. Than i have an other Struct with the Type of the first Struct. So now my first Question how can i better define the name and points than what i did down there. And Second Question how can i randomly get cards from an array of the structs. I hope anyone gets my Problem :)

```
struct CardInfos
{
    string name;
    int points;
};

struct cards
{
    CardInfos zwei;
    CardInfos drei;
    CardInfos vier;
    CardInfos fuenf;
    CardInfos sechs;
    CardInfos sieben;
    CardInfos acht;
    CardInfos neun;
    CardInfos Bube;
    CardInfos Königin;
    CardInfos König;
    CardInfos Ass;
};
```

Defined in a function in cpp....Better way?

```
cardIn.zwei.name = "Zwei";
cardIn.zwei.points = 2;
cardIn.zwei.name = "Drei";
cardIn.zwei.points = 3;
cardIn.zwei.name = "Vier";
cardIn.zwei.points = 4;
cardIn.zwei.name = "Fuenf";
cardIn.zwei.points = 5;
cardIn.zwei.name = "Sechs";
cardIn.zwei.points = 6;
cardIn.zwei.name = "Sieben";
cardIn.zwei.points = 7;
cardIn.zwei.name = "Acht";
cardIn.zwei.points = 8;
cardIn.zwei.name = "Neun";
cardIn.zwei.points = 9;
```

Comment: `cardIn.zwei.name = "Drei";
cardIn.zwei.points = 3;` and following doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: you seem to have a basic misunderstaning what class members are. The type `cards` is a class and if you create an instances of it, then each instance will have the members (`zwei`,`drei` ...). I dont see how this would be of any use. If you want to store the card infos somewhere you'd rather use a `std::array<CardInfo,12>`. Please try to clarify, what is `cards` supposed to be good for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cards, look more like a namespace to me, but both can work like this:

```
namespace cards {
    CardInfos zwei{"zwei", 2};
    CardInfos drei;//and so on
    CardInfos vier;
    CardInfos fuenf;
    CardInfos sechs;
    CardInfos sieben;
    CardInfos acht;
    CardInfos neun;
    CardInfos Bube;
    CardInfos Königin;
    CardInfos König;
    CardInfos Ass;
};
```

Comment: Yep, that's the badger. If you're doing it in a header, though, you're going to need some linkage antics. (`inline` ought to do it these days)